# Vue.js Router: history mode and AWS S3 (RoutingRules)

Tags: amazon-s3, vue.js, vue-router, s3-rewrite-rules

I have a Vue.js application up and running with Amazon S3 and Cloudflare.

When I open the index and browse to /dashboard, everything works fine. But when I open a route like dashboard directly in a new tab or refresh the page, I get the following error back from S3:

```
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: unternehmen
RequestId: 6514F8A1F4C29235
HostId: +BVrPLJSGdzSYogzWZ4GMBXkgkdSJWRVJVhcSs4EI/lmMUR422aCtCxpBGU6AMe5VkS1UbEn/Lc=
```

Just read that the problem is Vue.js history mode: https://router.vuejs.org/de/essentials/history-mode.html

I would like to solve the problem with a routing rule in my Amazon S3 Bucket. How would the Apache RewriteRule look for S3?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Tried the following but it does not work:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>domain.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

If I do it like that I just get my Header and Footer rendered but nothing more.

Thank you!

Comment: So... you turned off history mode?

Comment: Yeah, did not get it working with S3 and history mode.

Comment: @mrks Did the accepted Answer [S3 redirect] work with Hash mode for you?

Comment: when you set up your S3 bucket as a static website bucket, you have 2 fields: index document and error document. all you need to do is to populate the same value for index and error — "index.html" and vue router will take care of the rest

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I know this answer comes late but in case someone else is looking for another way to solve this in cloudfront, there's no need to create custom pages on s3 redirecting users when pages are not found. Instead of doing it, custom error responses can be created in cloudfront for the distribution.

[image: Custom errors]

This will always redirect to `/index.html` in case a file is not found and that will make the app route trigger.

Comment: I used the below answer in August. Now 7 months later, having the same question for a new app, your answer works better. Thanks!

Comment: This has solved it for me, without any changes in the application code or adding any rewriting rules to S3 or anything. Just this, now everything works.

Comment: If I could upvote this answer 100x over I would. It also solved the default directory problem I was having after enabling restricted bucket access using OAI; instead of needing to implement a ambda@Edge redirection function.

Comment: This is not a completely correct answer, the cache will be invalidated.
x-cache: Error from cloudfront

Answer (score 13):

If you use static hosting on AWS S3 and this is SPA app (React, Vue, Angular etc) you should set index.html as error page:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm hosting a static PWA made in Vue on S3 using "Static website hosting" and it works as expected.
What I did was quite simple - I've added this:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

To the Properties of the S3 bucket. See image below:
[image: S3 Properties]

For my S3 bucket, everytime you try to access a file that doesn't exist you will receive a 403 (forbidden) instead of a 404. That is why I've changed the HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals to 403. I've also replaced the ReplaceKeyWith with an empty string as "index.html" as not triggering the correct route.

I hope it helps.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: If you add one more routing rule for 404 then refresh (F5) is also handled correctly

Comment: The new S3 control panel only accepts JSON - adding the JSON rule here as well
`[{"Condition":{"HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals":"403"},"Redirect":{"ReplaceKeyWith":""}}]`

Answer (score 3):

I think this problem has two components:

1.

If a request is made directly (outside of the Javascript App) to a sub path such as /jobs then S3 returns a 404, because the path/object doesn't exist. The simplest way to fix this is from within S3 itself, where you redirect all error pages back to index.html.

However this doesn't work from a CDN such as Cloudfront, and presumably Cloudflare.

A good trick is to use files inside S3 that redirect users like this:

jobs/ -> /index.html
jobs -> /index.html

For example if someone makes a request to site/ they will get the following html file:

```
"redirect":"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://example.com/site/index.html\" /></head>
<body>Redirecting to <a href=\"http://example.com/site/index.html\">Home</a></body></html>"
```

Secondly...

> If I do it like that I just get my Header and Footer rendered but
>   nothing more.

This is a problem I've had where the router-view doesn't initialise properly, even though the component that contains the router-view has loaded.

What I have done for now is redirect my router when the main "App" component is created:

```
created () {
console.log('route', this.$route.path)
this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
}
```

This has the added bonus of removing the index.html from your path (Which was put there by your new redirections) whilst forcing your router-view to render...

My #app component is the parent component, with a navbar, footer, and the router-view that renders all of the sub pages/components.

Comment: NOTE: whilst this answer is accepted, it [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095823/vue-js-router-history-mode-and-aws-s3-routingrules?noredirect=1#comment76988309_43095823).

Comment: I was able to get it to work implementing this line: this.$router.replace(this.$route.fullPath || '/')

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work in with routing in history mode and without using CloudFront is to create the files that your URIs would point to. So let's say you use index.html as your entry point and have only one other page which you give path page2.html.

Then you should adapt your build and deploy process to do the following:

1. Build your source into a production distribution (E.g. using `npm run build`)
2. Make sure that for your router links you create a file per path that is a copy of the original file. In case of the example I mention it would be creating a copy of 'dist/index.html' to 'dist/page2.html'
3. Copy the dist folder contents to your S3 bucket

Note that the order of step 1 and 2 is important.
This can be easily done in a script that publishes your website.
I have just used this approach with the result I wanted; allowing refreshinag a page and opening links in a new tab.

Drawbacks I see is:
 - overhead of storing the copies of the files
 - have to make sure if you add a page not to forget to update your build and deploy scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer (403 and 404) did not work for me.
It was only after I added a similar **400 rule** did my VUE app function in history mode.

for anyone using an AWS SAM template:

```
  CloudFront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        ...
        CustomErrorResponses:
          - ErrorCode: 404
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
          - ErrorCode: 403
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
          - ErrorCode: 400
            ResponseCode: 200
            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

For those deploying a CloudFront distribution using AWS CDK.

Documentation is [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.Distribution.html#errorresponses)

Example cloudfront distribution with error responses deployed using Python CDK:

```py
origin_access_id = cloudfront.OriginAccessIdentity(scope=self, id="access_id")
self.website_bucket.grant_read(origin_access_id)

distribution = cloudfront.Distribution(
    scope=self,
    id="distribution",
    default_root_object="index.html",
    default_behavior=cloudfront.BehaviorOptions(
        origin=origins.S3Origin(
            bucket=self.website_bucket,
            origin_access_identity=origin_access_id,
        ),
        viewer_protocol_policy=cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
    ),

### ERROR RESPONSE SETUP
    error_responses=[
        cloudfront.ErrorResponse(
            http_status=403,
            response_http_status=200,
            response_page_path="/index.html",
        ),
        cloudfront.ErrorResponse(
            http_status=404,
            response_http_status=200,
            response_page_path="/index.html",
        ),
    ],
###
)
```