# Vue.js routing in AWS Cloudfront hosted website

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, amazon-cloudfront

I have a vuejs Nuxt  app which has index.vue at root. Then it has workflow/_id.vue sub folder to capture wild card pages at host.com/workflow/ABC123
It works fine in local. But in Cloudfront, it always goes to host.com/#!/workflow/ABC123
That way it always redirects to host.com/index.vue

Based on experience in angularjs, I added the replacewith key in s3 hosting params with "#!/"
But this is not working. What else shall I try?

Comment: I ran into something similar a while back, I'm guessing this has to do with the mode your Vue router is in. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095823/vue-js-router-history-mode-and-aws-s3-routingrules

Comment: I think one of the the problem is happening at pages where _id.vue pages exist. The above solution is already implemented and works fine. It is NuxtJS app.